# error: invalid use of template-name ‘ExTree’ without an argument list || How do if fix this? (Beginner)

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors

Where is the missing part? Or the other way around, what is wrong here? I am still new to C++ and things like this are very difficult to google and search for specifically.

```
template <typename T>
struct ExTree{
    T tensor;
    ExTree* left, *right;
};

template <typename T>
ExTree* newExTree<T>(T tensor){
    ExTree *e = new ExTree<T>();
    e->left = e->right = NULL;
    e->tensor = tensor;
    return e;
}
```

This is the error-message:

```
In file included from main.cpp:5:0:
expression.hpp:47:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘ExTree’ without an argument list
 ExTree* newExTree<T>(T tensor){
```

EDIT: I have found the error, but the reason behind it still eludes me, so my question is still kind of valid. I hope it is not to simple^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
template <typename T>
ExTree<T>* newExTree(T tensor){
    ExTree<T> *e = new ExTree<T>();
    e->left = e->right = nullptr;
    e->tensor = tensor;
    return e;
}
```

As the compiler tells you, `ExTree` is a template, not a type. If you write a template, that is not some "super-type" for all the types you create from it. It's basically just a block of code that is (re)created for every type (or combination of types) it is instantiated with; it is not some unifying concept. A template is *not* a type, and return *types* and variable *types* are, well, types, so you must specify which types to instantiate the template with to get a concrete type to use (ignoring certain C++14 rules that make things more muddy).

Further, you should not repeat the template argument after the function name as you did. That is done in the specialization of templates, but not in their initial declaration. For example, if you wanted to specialize `newExTree` for `T = int`, you would write

```
template<> ExTree<int>* newExTree<int>(int x) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I understand the request, but the problem is, that i would like to keep the template argument as generic as possible, because i might add more Tensor-classes later on. But i'll keep it in mind for now, thx

Comment: @CleboSevic The specialization thing was only as a demonstration/example, not a request that you should do it. The "fixed" code is indeed generic and should not need the specialization.